# Print out Average in for loop

Tags: java

This is my question

> get to input a positive integer representing a number of weeks, loop
>   continuously until the value entered is positive. For each week, enter
>   a value for liters and a value for kilometers. For each value, should
>   loop until the value entered is positive. both values is a real
>   number. Then output the fuel economy for that week (liters divided by
>   kilometers). Finally, output the average fuel economy. You must make
>   good use of submodules in your answer.

This is my work

```
import java.util.*;
public class Exam8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numweek = 0;
        double valkms = 0;
        double vallits = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double result = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of week: ");
        numweek = sc.nextInt();
        while (numweek < 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter a positive of number week: ");
            numweek = sc.nextInt();
        }
        while (true) {
             count++;
             System.out.print("Enter value of litres: : ");
             vallits = sc.nextDouble();
             while (vallits < 0) {
                 System.out.print("Positive litres: ");
                 vallits= sc.nextDouble();
             }
             System.out.print("Enter value of kilometres: : ");
             valkms = sc.nextDouble();
             while (valkms < 0) {
                 System.out.print("Positive kilometres: ");
                 valkms = sc.nextDouble();
             }
             if (vallits == 0 || valkms == 0) {
                 break;
             }
             result = vallits / valkms; 
             sum = result + (double)count;
             System.out.println(result); 
        }
        //average = getAverg(sum,count);
        System.out.print("Average of fuel economy is: " + average);
    }

    public static double getAverg(double sum, int count) {
        double average;
        average = sum/count;
        return average;
    }
}
```

I get a problem when input value of lit and km, for example, I like to stop when to put either of a value of lit or km. Then I have another problem with outputting an average of the result (lit/km).

Comment: You know... you can put the logic to read only positive integer in a method. It's even stated in the assignment: " _You must make good use of submodules in your answer_ " (Albeit it's badly worded) I hope that you have paid attention in the class.

Comment: I know I can put the logic in a method, but I have struggled with using submodules. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I believe that the person that wrote the assignment used "submodules" as synonym of methods. If you have put the positive check in a method, your task will be more easy to achieve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
import java.util.*;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numweek = 0;
        double valkms = 0;
        double vallits = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double result = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of week: ");
        numweek = sc.nextInt();
        while (numweek < 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter a positive of number week: ");
            numweek = sc.nextInt();
        }
        while (count < numweek) {
             count++;
             System.out.print("Enter value of litres: : ");
             vallits = sc.nextDouble();
             while (vallits < 0) {
                 System.out.print("Positive litres: ");
                 vallits= sc.nextDouble();
             }
             System.out.print("Enter value of kilometres: : ");
             valkms = sc.nextDouble();
             while (valkms < 0) {
                 System.out.print("Positive kilometres: ");
                 valkms = sc.nextDouble();
             }
             if (vallits == 0 || valkms == 0) {
                 break;
             }
             result = vallits / valkms; 
             sum += result;
             System.out.println(result); 
        }       
        System.out.print("Average of fuel economy is: " + getAverg(sum, numweek));
    }

    public static double getAverg(double sum, double numOfWeeks) {
        double average;
        average = sum/numOfWeeks;
        return average;
    }
}
```

Your first error was that the condition in the while loop wasn't correct. In order for the loop to stop you need to specify proper conditions. If condition is true it will loop indefinetely or until you set break.

Your second error was that you didn't calculate the average correctly. You should have just taken the sum for every week and added it to the current sum(which is zero at the beggining), and then just divide that sum by number of weeks to get the average.

You also didn't use your getAverg function anywhere.